# how to pass a link as paramameter in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink

i want to pass a domain link with http or https protocol as parameter in the link 
for example

http://www.payskip.me/url.php?go=https://www.oast.com

problem is when i pass the link without .com or any other extension it works well
like if i pass

http://www.payskip.me/url.php?go=https://www.oast.pk

its working but when i pass the link with .com its not working
example

http://www.payskip.me/url.php?go=https://www.oast.com

please tell me how can i solve this

Comment: It just worked? I got redirected to oast.com..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL encode the parameter, see [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

```
http://www.payskip.me/url.php?go=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oast.com
```

There is a [`url_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function in php.